# Duplicate foreign key in code-first EF added in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

i have a class entity for users table this :

```
[Table("Users", Schema = "Membership")]
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(450)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int? StateID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StateID")]
    public virtual Place.State State { get; set; }

 }
```

and related to class state

```
[Table("States", Schema = "Place")]

public class State
{
    public State()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

but after i update-database i see added new extra key State_Id , my forign key defined StateID in code but u can see final table have a 2 forign key in table database.
[image: users table image]

Comment: Update database will execute sql queries/commands from migration files, check "Up" methods of  last migrations.

Comment: May it be you have defined additional foregin key in your `OnModelCreating` procedure?

Comment: after run command add-migration we can change migration script ?

Comment: in OnModelCreating i havn't relation for this table or related onli have this 
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            
  
  modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

Comment: now i see in OnModelCreating i have relation for parent current class for affiliateid              modelBuilder.Entity<Model.Membership.User>()
                  .HasOptional(c => c.Affiliate)
                  .WithMany()
                  .HasForeignKey(c => c.AffiliateID);       maybe added for this relation ? but why not added other relation